# how to weight means based on data set size

Tags: distributions

Let's say I have a list of lists of integers, all of a large variance in length, and I want to get the weighted mean of each record. How would I go about doing that?

For example:

```
record_a = [1];
record_b = [8, 7, 5, 6, 7, 2, 9];
record_c = [8];
record_d = [8, 4, 5];
record_e = [8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,]
```

There will always be under 10,000 records in this list

To clarify, for instance if I want to compare the mean of record E and record A there is a large difference in data and I am not sure how to weight to account for that.

Comment: Hi Aria. Welcome to CV. When you say "weighted mean", what are you weighting by?

Comment: If you just want the mean, and some measure of uncertainty, you can take the mean and standard error of each `record_i` (noting that the SE doesn't exist if you only have one number in a record such as `a` and `c`)

Comment: @AlexJ Sorry for the confusion, I am basically calculating win-rates for a game based on a unique team. Some teams have 1 games, while others have many games and so it seems unfair to compare the means of the two straight up knowing ones data set is much more vast.

I am wondering how I could say compare the winrate of a team with 2 games, and the a team with 100 games while making sure its balanced.

Comment: Also I should note I am not extremely math literate, so sorry if this is a silly question to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mean and standard error for each record.

For example, record b: the mean is 6.29 and the standard error ($=\frac{\text{sample standard deviation}}{\sqrt{n}}$) is 0.87. Contrast this to record d: the mean is 5.67 and the standard error is 1.3. So, if we wanted to compare them, we can say we are a lot more certain about the win rate for team b, compared with that for team d.

There is a lot of available information on standard errors on the Internet.

Comment: Awesome thanks!